# Slider in Apple store style javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios

I know I would show some effort in this but I have no idea... I'm trying to make a slider like the one in the home section of Apple website.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qx1n2.jpg)
How do I make a click on a picture to flip through a slide? Or how do I make it scroll? Can you give me a hint?

https://www.apple.com/

Made a small copy but ran into difficulties. Such as automatic scrolling.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up the basic structure of your slider. Create a container element to hold the slides, and within it, add individual slide elements.

**.html**

```
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="slide">
    <!-- Content for slide 1 -->
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <!-- Content for slide 2 -->
  </div>
  <!-- Add more slide elements as needed -->
</div>
```

Apply CSS styles to position the slides, create the desired layout, and hide any overflow.

**.css**

```
.slider-container {
  width: 100%; /* Set the desired width */
  height: 400px; /* Set the desired height */
  overflow: hidden; /* Hide overflowing content */
  position: relative; /* Establish a positioning context for the slides */
}

.slide {
  width: 100%; /* Set the slide width */
  height: 100%; /* Set the slide height */
  position: absolute; /* Position the slides absolutely */
  top: 0; /* Align slides to the top of the container */
  left: 0; /* Align slides to the left of the container */
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out; /* Apply a transition effect for smooth sliding */
}
```

To enable click or scroll functionality, you'll need to use JavaScript. Here's an example using JavaScript to handle clicks and automatically scroll the slides.

**.js**

```
const sliderContainer = document.querySelector('.slider-container');
const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
let currentIndex = 0;

function showSlide(index) {
  slides.forEach((slide, i) => {
    slide.style.transform = `translateX(-${index * 100}%)`;
  });
}

function handleClick() {
  currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % slides.length;
  showSlide(currentIndex);
}

function startAutoScroll() {
  setInterval(() => {
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % slides.length;
    showSlide(currentIndex);
  }, 3000); // Adjust the time interval between slides (in milliseconds)
}

showSlide(currentIndex); // Show the initial slide
sliderContainer.addEventListener('click', handleClick); // Handle click events
startAutoScroll(); // Start automatic scrolling
```

Remember to adjust the class names and styling to match your HTML structure and desired visual appearance.